# python keeps returning typeerror: unhashable type: list

Tags: python

im not that good in programming, just doing it for fun and getting code samples online. so i decided i wanted to do the following:

1. count total word number
2. count 'whereby' words
3. divide 'whereby' count on total word number

However, i keep getting 'unhashable type: 'list'. I assume that this is because I use frequency_list but I don't understand how do i go about that.

**Error traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\whereby.py", line 31, in 
    print(int(frequency[words])/wordCount)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

```
import re
import string

frequency = {}
wherebyity = {}
document_text = open('C:/Users/user/desktop/text.txt', 'r')
text_string = document_text.read().lower()
match_pattern = re.findall('whereby', text_string)

for word in match_pattern:
    count = frequency.get(word, 0)
    frequency[word] = count + 1

frequency_list = frequency.keys()

for words in frequency_list:
    print (words, frequency[words])
    print (type(frequency))
    print (type(frequency[words]))
    print (frequency)

with open('C:/Users/user/desktop/text.txt', 'r') as f:
    p = f.read() # p contains contents of entire file
    # logic to compute word counts follows here...
    words = p.split()
    wordCount = len(words)
    print ("The total word count is:", wordCount)
    print (type(wordCount))


    print(int(frequency[words])/wordCount)
```

Comment: Can we see the error trace?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\whereby.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(int(frequency[words])/wordCount)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: I suspect 'words' is a list, not a keyword - you cannot use a list as a dict keyword. Check 'words' in the debugger and verify that it is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

In your `words = p.split()` line you are setting `words` to be a `list` object from splitting.

Your error is saying you cannot get the item at the index of `words` in `frequency` in your last line since `list`s cannot be hashed. You can read more about how Python dictionaries work and why hashing is a thing they use [here](https://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-dictionary-implementation/).

I think you mean to put something else instead of `words` in your last line, maybe `'whereby'`.